# How to auto bind plugin initializations for content loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, binding, live

I'm using expandable plugin by Brandon Aaron to auto grow my textareas in the form and it is working ok. 
the problem  is that I'm loading a lot of pages through ajax so I need to rebind the plugin method to the textareas loaded through ajax.

is there a way to do this kind of method calls like

```
$("textarea").expandable();
```

through live() or delegate() in jQuery. it'll make my code much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.liveQuery` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) still has a use here, it's not *entirely* replaced by jQuery core's `.live()`, here's how your example would work:

```
$("textarea").liveQuery(function() {
  $(this).expandable();
});
```

`.livequery()` actually watches for new elements, unlike `.live()` which listens for events to bubble up the DOM, they operate in very different ways.

Comment: Thanks man, this actually made my day. I've totally forgotten about the liveQuery plugin after 1.4 release, cause they added live submit and blur which was not possible with liveQuery. Thanks for reminding me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Only events can be binded, plugins have to be called with every new element.

[Edit]

Events aren't binded to new elements, the events are just caught on the bubbling/capturing phase on the way to the element, allowing for new elements to be added and events can still be handled.

Plugins are binded to the element set returned by the init constructor. It is up to plugin developers to use event delegation within their plugin to capture new elements being added within the element scope they were attached to (or they can go outside to the document and risk clashing with other plugins).

Comment: if that's the case, this sounds like a great idea for a plugin. something like live-plugin-binding.
a lot of plugins will add a method to jQuery that should be called to initialize. it would be great if a plugin can handle this on the fly just like live.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would personally go about this is have the plugin initialize in a function and call that function when the ajax load is completed.My laptop battery is low so my syntax is probably a little off but the idea is there.

```
function foo()
{
   $('.classSelector').plugin();
}

$('.eventListener').load('url', function()
{
    foo();
})
```